how to do perfect forwarding when the template argument is explicitly declared
Consider this simple function
template <typename U>
auto mkVector(U&& x0)
{
    return std::vector<std::decay_t<U>>{std::forward<U>(x0)};
}

and 4 possible use cases where the argument is either an l-value or an r-value, and the type is either implicitly stated or deducted from the arguments:
    const string lvalue("hello");

    // type inferred from arguments
    auto v1 = mkVector(lvalue);              // argument is a lvalue
    auto v2 = mkVector(string{});            // argument is a rvalue

    // type is explicilty stated
    auto v3 = mkVector<string>(lvalue);       // argument is a lvalue
    auto v4 = mkVector<string>("");           // argument is a rvalue

The case v3 fails to compile, because U is explicitly declared U=string, therefore U&& means string&& and lvalue is not compatible.
Is there a way to write the function mkVector so that it works in all possible cases correctly supporting perfect forwarding?
The best I could come up with is to write two overloads of the function, but that is not ideal and if there are N arguments instead of 1, would require 2^N possible overloads.
template <typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_rvalue_reference_v<U>, bool> = true>
auto mkVector(U&& x0)
{
    return std::vector<U>{std::move(x0)};
}

template <typename U>
auto mkVector(const U& x0)
{
    return std::vector<U>{x0};
}


It depends what you want to achieve. What is the intended meaning of mkVector<string> with the explicit template argument?

There is a family of template containers (e.g. my_array_t) defined for a small set of types (e.g. string). I want to be able to write makeContainer(value1, value2, ...) where all values could be lvalues or values, of the same type used in the container or cast-able to the type of the container. For example, the container is defined for string but not defined on const char*, in which case, to I have to explicitly state the container type: makeContainer<string>("hi", "hello").

You ideally want something like this:
template <typename T = std::decay_t<U>, typename U>
auto mkVector(U&& x0) {
    return std::vector<T>{std::forward<U>(x0)};
}

... Where T defaults to std::decay_t<U> if not explicitly specified. However this doesn't work as a default can't refer to a later argument.
You can use a "placeholder" type that you know won't be explicitly specified, like void, and replace it with the default if it's the placeholder
template<typename T = void, typename U>
auto mkVector(U&& x0) {
    using type = std::conditional_t<std::is_void_v<T>, std::decay_t<U>, T>;
    return std::vector<type>{ std::forward<U>(x0) };
}

I don't know what you mean by "would require 2^N possible overloads". If you had more arguments, you couldn't explicitly specify the second argument without explicitly specifying the first, so at most you would need N+1 overloads. For multiple arguments, you can do something like this:
namespace detail {
template<std::size_t N, typename Default, typename... Types>
auto nth_or_impl() {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Types) > N) {
        return std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Types...>>{};
    } else {
        return std::enable_if<true, Default>{};
    }
}
}

template<std::size_t N, typename Default, typename... Types>
using nth_or = typename decltype(detail::nth_or_impl<N, Default, Types...>)_)::type;

template <typename... T, typename U0, typename U1, typename U2>
auto f(U0&& x0, U1&& u1, U2&& u2) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(T) <= 3, "f: Explicitly specified more than 3 template arguments");
    using T1 = nth_or<0, std::decay_t<U0>, T...>;
    using T2 = nth_or<1, std::decay_t<U1>, T...>;
    using T3 = nth_or<2, std::decay_t<U2>, T...>;
    // ...
}

This also supports parameter packs of unknown size.


Is there a way to write the function mkVector so that it works in all possible cases correctly supporting perfect forwarding?

No, there isn't.
You can either use a forwarding reference and be at the whim of a user providing a bogus U, or basically implement all functionality of std::forward within mkVector.
You need at least two overloads for that, so you're on the right track, but I wouldn't pursue that idea any further; it's a waste of time.
The real concern here is that the user can break stuff by providing explicit template arguments, and this isn't a problem limited to just perfect forwarding.
Consider the following example:
template <typename T>
void f(T x) {
    use(std::move(x));
}

If the user called f<U&>(u) explicitly, then f would move from the given u, not from a local copy.
There are lots of standard library functions that aren't implemented in a way that's robust against explicit arguments (for example, std::swap) too.
This is a really basic issue with C++ that's much more widespread than one may think.
So ... what do we do about it? You have two options:

Don't care. mkVector is not supposed to be used with explicit arguments, and the user is to blame if they misuse it like that.
Prevent the user from passing anything (useful) explicitly.

For the latter approach, you can write:
template <typename..., typename U>
auto mkVector(U&& x0)
{
    return std::vector<std::decay_t<U>>{std::forward<U>(x0)};
}

Any explicit arguments provided to mkVector will be gobbled up by typename..., so the user cannot specify U explicitly anymore.
This technically works, but it's pretty unusual.
Most people just don't care.

Thanks for your reply. Here I am porting to C+17 a 100 millions line code library written in C++98.  Currently I have mkvector(const T1& a1),  mkvector(const T1& a1, const T2& a2), ... up to 20 arguments. The explicit template arguments are needed in situation where the container is of a type (e.g. string) and the arguments passed are of another type (e.g. const char *).  All 4 use cases I described appear millions of times in all flavours. If there is no other way to do this, I suppose I have to give up on perfect forwarding and define the arguments are const Ts&....

By the way, nice trick the one to gobble explicit parameters typename... !

Yeah ... I don't seen an easy fix to dummy-proof these functions while keeping the call site the same. You'll just have to insert a typename... to separate the arguments that need to be provided explicitly from the deduced ones and update the call site if there is misuse. The good news is that the overwhelming majority of function templates shouldn't receive any explicit template arguments. Stuff like std::forward and std::get are rare exceptions, but there's usually a way to avoid it.

Maybe static_assert(!std::is_reference_v<T>); ... although I feel that it is very hard to make C++ foolproof.

@Eljay for the example with f, yeah, that's a start. For mkVector, a forwarding reference U&& an deduce U to be an non-reference, or an lvalue reference. The only bogus case that can't happen without explicitly provided arguments is U being deduced to an rvalue reference. However, that shouldn't happen when the code base is currently C++98 anyway.

@jan, perhaps a solution is to use your typename..., then create some traits which convert all possible types into the small set of types for which are relevant for my container exists. E.g. traits<const char *>::type is string, traits<any integral type>::type is int, etc...

You could name that initial typename... and do some metaprogramming processing on those if you really need both syntaxes to work. Sounds unlikely to be worth the effort, though.

template<class T, class U>
concept compatible = std::is_convertible_v<T, std::decay_t<U>> || std::is_void_v<U>;

template<class X, class Alt>
using fallback_t = std::conditional_t<std::is_void_v<X>, Alt, X>;

template <class T = void, compatible<T> U>
auto mkVector(U&& x0) {
  using V = fallback_t< T, std::decay_t<U> >;
  return std::vector<V>{std::forward<U>(x0)};
}

This creates an mkVector factory function.  It optionally can be passed a type T.  If it is passed a type T, it creates a vector of that type and ensures that your argument can be stored in a vector of that type.
Failure to be compatible generates a overload resolution error due to concept mismatch.
Otherwise, it creates a vector of std::decay_t<U> where U is the passed value's type.
This scales to more arguments easily, without requiring 2^n manual implementations.  For example
template<class K=void, class V=void, compatible<K>, Ku, compatible<V> Vu>
auto mkMap( Ku&& k, Vu&& v ) {
  using Km = fallback_t< K, std::decay_t<Ku> >;
  using Vm = fallback_t< V, std::decay_t<Vu> >;
  return std::map< Km, Vm >( { std::forward<Ku>(k), std::forward<Vu>(v) } );
}

with linear code, not exponential code.
